# flutter share received pusher data between screens using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, pusher, flutter-provider, riverpod

In our system we used `Pusher` on both of our `Admin Panel` and `mobile` application, in `flutter` i want to wrap whole application screens with `Pusher` and `Riverpod` and using providers with `Hook` widget in screens, that means i want to implement `Pusher` in `main` or `MyApp` and broadcast received data from `Pusher` on all of screens which we have them, basically we had to use `Pusher` in each screen which we need to receive data and its difficult to maintain application, for example:

[image]

this sample code is not correct and i tried to implement that, but i can't

here as you can see `Pusher` events and listeners work fine without any problem:

```
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): [BIND] new-login
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): [BIND] new-login
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): [ON_EVENT] Channel: backers-list, EventName: new-login,
D/PusherClientPlugin( 7447): Data: Sending Test Data , User Id: null
I/flutter ( 7447): received
```

`SpashScreen` class as initializing `Pusher`

```dart
class SplashScreen extends HookWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _routeNavigation();
    final PusherClient pusher = PusherClient(
        "xxxx",
        PusherOptions(
        cluster: 'us2',
    ));
    final Channel channel;

    pusher.connect();

    channel = pusher.subscribe("backers-list");

    channel.bind("new-login", (event) {
      print('received');
      context
          .read(alarmNotificationStateProvider.notifier)
          .increment('${event?.data.toString()}');
    });

    return Scaffold(
      /* ... */
```

`Profile` screen should be receive data from `Pusher` which i implemented that into `SplashScreen`

```dart
class Profile extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alarmNotification = useProvider(alarmNotificationStateProvider);
    print('PUSH RECEIVED');
    /* ... */
}
```

`alarmNotificationStateProvider` :

```
final alarmNotificationStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AlarmNotification, AlarmNotificationData>(
      (ref) => AlarmNotification(),
);
```

`AlarmNotification` class:

```dart
class AlarmNotification extends StateNotifier<AlarmNotificationData> {
  AlarmNotification() : super(_initialValue);

  static const _initialValue = AlarmNotificationData('');

  void increment(String data) {
    state = AlarmNotificationData(data);
  }
}
```

`AlarmNotificationData` class:

```dart
class AlarmNotificationData {
  final String data;

  const AlarmNotificationData(this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To listen changes in `riverpod` you require `useProvider(provider);`

The `useProvider` method will listen for state changes in provider, which is the current instance of your model class

This also gives you a reference to the notifier state, which you’re storing in model class

use this:

```
final alarmNotificationNotifier  = useProvider(alarmNotificationProvider);
```

instead of `final alarmNotificationNotifier = context.read(alarmNotificationProvider);`

the `read` method gets you a reference to your state management class (CounterNotifier) without listening for changes in the state

Comment: this implementation is for `Provider` not `Riverpod`

Comment: @DolDurma Have you used useProvider method in your classes to listen for state changes?

Comment: i tried to implement that, but i can't, could you give me a sample how can i do that? your answer couldn't help me on implementation

Comment: Instead of writing lengthy example code here, to better understand concept I found this blog. This might help to you
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-riverpod-tutorial-counter-app-ed3aa758f02f

Comment: i should upgrade my account on `medium`, as we can't pay money in this site which boycotted our country i couldn't read document

Comment: try to open in incognito otherwise I will share you code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235084/discussion-between-doldurma-and-nik).

Comment: @DolDurma updated example code in conversation

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your code of `AlarmNotification`, so I use a simple version below.

```
class AlarmNotification extends ChangeNotifier{    
  var _data;
  String get data => _data;

  void receivedData(String data){
    _data = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I think you misunderstand a little about riverpod. The `MyApp` seems only **provide** the event data but not consume it. So the part you can just use StatelessWidget.(It is also suggested to use "context.read(someProvider)" if you only read not watch)

```
final alarmNotificationProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref)=>AlarmNotification());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({Key? key}):super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ...

    channel.bind("new-login", (event) {
      context
          .read(alarmNotificationProvider)
          .receivedData('${event?.data.toString()}');
    });

    ...
  }
}
```

And the other widgets that need the data just listen to the `alarmNotificationProvider` (you may need to import the file to see it). It will rebuild the widget once it gets the notification.

```
class OtherWidget extends HookWidget {
  const OtherWidget({Key? key}):super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alarmNotification = useProvider(alarmNotificationProvider);
    
    return Text(alarmNotification.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i combined your answer with Nik

Answer (score 0):

We are also using pusher. We are using flutter_pusher package and notifications work as expected. you can initialize it by
e.g.

```
Pusher.init('API_KEY', PusherOptions(encrypted:true));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way,

/// Code

```
 runApp(
  MultiProvider(
   providers: [
     ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsProvider>(
       create: (context) => SettingsProvider(),
     ),   
   ],
   child: MyApp(),
  ),
 );
```

///

```
class SettingsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _currentLocale = Locale("en", "");
  String _languageCode = "en";

  Locale get getCurrentLocale => _currentLocale;

  String get getLanguageCode => _languageCode;

  void updateLocale(Locale locale) {
    Log.loga(title, "updateLocale: >>>> $locale");
    Log.loga(title, "updateLocale: toLanguageTag >>>> ${locale.toLanguageTag()}");

    this._currentLocale = locale;
    AppTranslations.load(locale);
    this._languageCode = locale.toLanguageTag();

  //notifyListeners();
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) {
    super.notifyListeners();
  });
 }
}

/// update data
Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context, listen: false).updateLocale(locale);

/// get data
Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context).getCurrentLocale
```

Comment: The question is about Riverpod and not Provider

Answer (score -1):

make sure both screeens are under the changenotifier in widget tree,

other option is pass your provider to login screen as argument and use changenotifier.value() in login screen,