# The way to disable button using provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Provider and trying to make buttons disable without StatfulWidgets.
But I can't find the way to do it.

What I did:

```
class CLS with ChangeNotifier {
    bool pressed = false;
    bool detect(return pressed;);
    void pressed(pressed = true;)
}

....

//StatelessWidget
ElevatedButton(
  ...
  onPressed: Provider.of<CLS>(context, listen: false).detect()
             ? null : context.read<CLS>().pressed(),
  ...
)
```

I know buttons are disabled when `onPressed` is null. So I want to make it dynamicaly, but buttons color is not changed. `CLS.pressed` becomes `true` when button is pressed.

What sohould I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use notify listeners in your CLS class

```
class CLS with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _pressed = false;
  bool detect() {
    return _pressed;
  }

  void pressed() {
    _pressed = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

You should also remove `listen:false` from your `onPressed` provider listener to be able to react to the changes

```
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: Provider.of<CLS>(context).detect()
              ? null
              : () => context.read<CLS>().pressed(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code. Refer this link for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418866/16467763

//StatelessWidget

```
ElevatedButton(
  ...
  onPressed: Provider.of<CLS>(context).isDetect
             ? null : context.read<CLS>().pressed(),
  ...
)
```

//

```
class CLS with ChangeNotifier {
    bool _pressed = false;
   
    bool get isDetect => _pressed;

    void pressed() {
       this._pressed  = true;
   
       Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) {
          super.notifyListeners();
       });
    }
}
```